# Regular expression for condition until next space

Tags: regex, r

How would I write a regular expression that grabs a capital letter located anywhere then any subsequent character until a space?

Input: 
`cake pietypeAPPLE CRUMBLE tart toastTexas price`

For example, I would want to grab "APPLE" despite it not being preceded by a space. I want "CRUMBLE". I also want "Texas" even though not all of its components are upper case.

I will use `gsub(pattern, replacement = "", x = string)` to get the following output

Output:
`cake pietype tart toast price`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `regmatches` to extract these substrings.

```
> x <- 'cake pietypeAPPLE CRUMBLE tart toastTexas price'
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('[A-Z]\\S+', x))[[1]]
# [1] "APPLE"   "CRUMBLE" "Texas"
```

Alternatively, if you want to be strict on matching letter characters only.

```
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('[A-Z][A-Za-z]+', x))[[1]]
```

If you want to replace them, I would use the following to avoid excess space left in between the words.

```
> gsub('[A-Z][A-Za-z]+( [A-Z][A-Za-z]+)*', '', x)
# [1] "cake pietype tart toast price"
```

Comment: Worked. `S` is space?

Comment: `\S` matches any non-whitespace, `\s` matches whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the `qdapRegex` package:

```
x <- 'cake pietypeAPPLE CRUMBLE tart toastTexas price'

library(qdapRegex)
rm_default(x, pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z]*")

## [1] "cake pietype tart toast price"
```

If you want to extract these terms:

```
rm_default(x, pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z]*", extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "APPLE"   "CRUMBLE" "Texas"
```